# Show PKDrawing on macOS in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, pencilkit

Is it possible to display a `PKDrawing` on macOS that was previously created on an iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a new `PKDrawing` object from your drawing data and generate a `NSImage` from it:

```
import PencilKit
```

---

```
do {
    let pkDrawing = try PKDrawing(data: drawingData)
    let nsImage = pkDrawing.image(from: pkDrawing.bounds, scale: view.window?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Do you know another way? Because rendering the image takes a huge amount of space and is very inefficient.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "takes a huge amount of space". You are the only one who can decide the resolution and the type of data representation thats gonna be used.

Comment: The image is saved in a file. The resolution should be as high as possible, so the image consumes a lot of storage space (what I don't want), in contrast to the PKDrawing. Is it possible in any other way to represent the PKDrawing on macOS instead of an image?

Comment: Just save the drawingData

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid. I just discovered that PencilKit is not iOS only, I thought it was not available on macOS, but it is. Thank you for your help!